# Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mybatis

The proble is that, every time I run the project the error from org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException pop-up.

I've already tried several related questions in stack with answers but the problem isn't resolved yet.

FieldDataService.java

```
@Component
public interface FieldDataService {
       public FieldData getFieldData() throws SQLException, Exception;

}
```

FieldDataServiceImpl.java

```
@Component
public class FieldDataServiceImpl implements FieldDataService {

    @Autowired
    FieldDataDao fieldDataDao;

    @Override
    public FieldData getFieldData() throws SQLException, Exception {
        return this.fieldDataDao.getFieldData();
    }
}
```

FieldDataDao.java

```
@Component
public interface FieldDataDao {

    public FieldData getFieldData() throws SQLException, Exception;
}
```

FieldDataDaoImpl.java

```
@Component
public class FieldDataDaoImpl implements FieldDataDao{

    @Autowired
    private SqlSession sqlSession;

    @Override
    public FieldData getFieldData() throws SQLException, Exception {
        FieldData result = new FieldData();

        try {
            result = this.sqlSession.selectOne("getFieldData");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

FieldData.java

```
@Component
public class FieldData {

    private String transactionType;
    private String distribution;
    private Date startDate;
    private Date endDate;
    private String reportType;

    public String getTransactionType() {
        return transactionType;
    }
    public void setTransactionType(String transactionType) {
        this.transactionType = transactionType;
    }
    public String getDistribution() {
        return distribution;
    }
    public void setDistribution(String distribution) {
        this.distribution = distribution;
    }
    public Date getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }
    public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }
    public Date getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }
    public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }
    public String getReportType() {
        return reportType;
    }
    public void setReportType(String reportType) {
        this.reportType = reportType;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "FieldData [transactionType=" + transactionType + ", distribution=" + distribution + ", startDate="
                + startDate + ", endDate=" + endDate + ", reportType=" + reportType + "]";
    }
}
```

FieldData.xml

```
<mapper namespace="com.pnb.allianz.jdt.maper.FieldData">
     <resultMap id="FieldDataResultMap" type="FielData">
        <result column="LF2S_TRAN_TYPE"         property="transactionType"/>
        <result column="LF2S_DISTRIBUTION"      property="distribution"/>
        <result column="LF2S_REPORT_TYPE"   property="reportType"/>
    </resultMap>

    <select id="getFieldData" resultMap="FieldDataResultMap">
        SELECT * FROM LF2S_MR_PARAMETERS
        WHERE rownum =1
    </select>
</mapper>
```

..and the error goes like this

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'generateJdtController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'fieldDataService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'fieldDataServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'fieldDataDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'fieldDataDaoImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sqlSession'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'sqlSessionTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory]: Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'fieldDataService' defined in file [C:\Users\markanthony.ragay\Desktop\julia-document-tracking\julia-document-tracking\target\classes\com\pnb\allianz\jdt\service\FieldDataService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory]: Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'fieldDataService' defined in file [C:\Users\markanthony.ragay\Desktop\julia-document-tracking\julia-document-tracking\target\classes\com\pnb\allianz\jdt\service\FieldDataService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'fieldDataDao' defined in file [C:\Users\markanthony.ragay\Desktop\julia-document-tracking\julia-document-tracking\target\classes\com\pnb\allianz\jdt\dao\FieldDataDao.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory]: Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'fieldDataDao' defined in file [C:\Users\markanthony.ragay\Desktop\julia-document-tracking\julia-document-tracking\target\classes\com\pnb\allianz\jdt\dao\FieldDataDao.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory]: Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'fieldDataDao' defined in file [C:\Users\markanthony.ragay\Desktop\julia-document-tracking\julia-document-tracking\target\classes\com\pnb\allianz\jdt\dao\FieldDataDao.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'fieldDataService' defined in file [C:\Users\markanthony.ragay\Desktop\julia-document-tracking\julia-document-tracking\target\classes\com\pnb\allianz\jdt\service\FieldDataService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory]: Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'fieldDataService' defined in file [C:\Users\markanthony.ragay\Desktop\julia-document-tracking\julia-document-tracking\target\classes\com\pnb\allianz\jdt\service\FieldDataService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory]: Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'fieldDataService' defined in file [C:\Users\markanthony.ragay\Desktop\julia-document-tracking\julia-document-tracking\target\classes\com\pnb\allianz\jdt\service\FieldDataService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'fieldDataDao' defined in file [C:\Users\markanthony.ragay\Desktop\julia-document-tracking\julia-document-tracking\target\classes\com\pnb\allianz\jdt\dao\FieldDataDao.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory]: Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'fieldDataDao' defined in file [C:\Users\markanthony.ragay\Desktop\julia-document-tracking\julia-document-tracking\target\classes\com\pnb\allianz\jdt\dao\FieldDataDao.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory]: Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'fieldDataDao' defined in file [C:\Users\markanthony.ragay\Desktop\julia-document-tracking\julia-document-tracking\target\classes\com\pnb\allianz\jdt\dao\FieldDataDao.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'fieldDataService' defined in file [C:\Users\markanthony.ragay\Desktop\julia-document-tracking\julia-document-tracking\target\classes\com\pnb\allianz\jdt\service\FieldDataService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory]: Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'fieldDataService' defined in file [C:\Users\markanthony.ragay\Desktop\julia-document-tracking\julia-document-tracking\target\classes\com\pnb\allianz\jdt\service\FieldDataService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory]: Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'fieldDataService' defined in file [C:\Users\markanthony.ragay\Desktop\julia-document-tracking\julia-document-tracking\target\classes\com\pnb\allianz\jdt\service\FieldDataService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'fieldDataDao' defined in file [C:\Users\markanthony.ragay\Desktop\julia-document-tracking\julia-document-tracking\target\classes\com\pnb\allianz\jdt\dao\FieldDataDao.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory]: Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'fieldDataDao' defined in file [C:\Users\markanthony.ragay\Desktop\julia-document-tracking\julia-document-tracking\target\classes\com\pnb\allianz\jdt\dao\FieldDataDao.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory]: Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'fieldDataDao' defined in file [C:\Users\markanthony.ragay\Desktop\julia-document-tracking\julia-document-tracking\target\classes\com\pnb\allianz\jdt\dao\FieldDataDao.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'fieldDataService' defined in file [C:\Users\markanthony.ragay\Desktop\julia-document-tracking\julia-document-tracking\target\classes\com\pnb\allianz\jdt\service\FieldDataService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory]: Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'fieldDataService' defined in file [C:\Users\markanthony.ragay\Desktop\julia-document-tracking\julia-document-tracking\target\classes\com\pnb\allianz\jdt\service\FieldDataService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory]: Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'fieldDataService' defined in file [C:\Users\markanthony.ragay\Desktop\julia-document-tracking\julia-document-tracking\target\classes\com\pnb\allianz\jdt\service\FieldDataService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'fieldDataDao' defined in file [C:\Users\markanthony.ragay\Desktop\julia-document-tracking\julia-document-tracking\target\classes\com\pnb\allianz\jdt\dao\FieldDataDao.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory]: Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'fieldDataDao' defined in file [C:\Users\markanthony.ragay\Desktop\julia-document-tracking\julia-document-tracking\target\classes\com\pnb\allianz\jdt\dao\FieldDataDao.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory]: Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'fieldDataDao' defined in file [C:\Users\markanthony.ragay\Desktop\julia-document-tracking\julia-document-tracking\target\classes\com\pnb\allianz\jdt\dao\FieldDataDao.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'fieldDataService' defined in file [C:\Users\markanthony.ragay\Desktop\julia-document-tracking\julia-document-tracking\target\classes\com\pnb\allianz\jdt\service\FieldDataService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory]: Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'fieldDataDao' defined in file [C:\Users\markanthony.ragay\Desktop\julia-document-tracking\julia-document-tracking\target\classes\com\pnb\allianz\jdt\dao\FieldDataDao.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'fieldDataDao' defined in file [C:\Users\markanthony.ragay\Desktop\julia-document-tracking\julia-document-tracking\target\classes\com\pnb\allianz\jdt\dao\FieldDataDao.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'fieldDataService' defined in file [C:\Users\markanthony.ragay\Desktop\julia-document-tracking\julia-document-tracking\target\classes\com\pnb\allianz\jdt\service\FieldDataService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
2019-04-08 14:30:32.380  INFO 2284 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-04-08 14:30:32.410  INFO 2284 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :
```

Thanks in advance guys. Hope you can help me.

Comment: I guess there is issue with your sql datasource ,its null .Check your connection settings

Comment: if your field data class is an entity then you should ass @Entity on that class. As you're using mybatis for DB interaction. Please correct if is is wrong.

Comment: Check your SessionFactory: The exception stacktrace indicates that: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory]: Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Also I would suggest to remove the @Component Annotation from your interfaces as they seem unnecessary.

Comment: @thehandofNOD I've tried removing @ Component annotation on interfaces but the error is still the same

Comment: @ShubhDixit  spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.transaction.rollback-on-commit-failure=true
#LOCAL
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@sddevdb2.myhouse.com:1555:JLDEV
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=user

mybatis.config=classpath:mybatis-config.xml

Comment: @ShubhDixit  `spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.transaction.rollback-on-commit-failure=true
#LOCAL
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@sddevdb2.myhouse.com:1555:JLDEV
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=user

mybatis.config=classpath:mybatis-config.xml`   this all located in application.properties

Comment: Try using: 
http://www.mybatis.org/spring-boot-starter/mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure/

There is also an example with SqlSession.

Comment: @Grauzoneit worked!! thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your `sqlSessionFactory`. this exception is `NullPointerException`.

**Your error message**

> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'sqlSessionTemplate'
>   parameter 0; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:     Error
>   creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path
>   resource [ 
>   org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:  Failed to
>   instantiate [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory]: Factory
>   method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NullPointerException